# Why don't Haskell list comprehensions cause an error when pattern match fails?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, list-comprehension

I'm trying to understand how Haskell list comprehensions work "under the hood" in regards to pattern matching. The following ghci output illustrates my point:

```
Prelude> let myList = [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing, Just 3]
Prelude> let xs = [x | Just x <- myList]
Prelude> xs
[1,2,3]
Prelude>
```

As you can see, it is able to skip the "Nothing" and select only the "Just" values. I understand that List is a monad, defined as (source from Real World Haskell, ch. 14):

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
    xs >> f = concat (map (\_ -> f) xs)
    fail _ = []
```

Therefore, a list comprehension basically builds a singleton list for every element selected in the list comprehension and concatenates them. If a pattern match fails at some step, the result of the "fail" function is used instead. In other words, the "Just x" pattern doesn't match so [] is used as a placeholder until 'concat' is called. That explains why the "Nothing" appears to be skipped.

What I don't understand is, how does Haskell know to call the "fail" function? Is it "compiler magic", or functionality that you can write yourself in Haskell? Is it possible to write the following "select" function to work the same way as a list comprehension?

```
select :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
select (Just x -> x) myList       -- how to prevent the lambda from raising an error?
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While implemenatations of Haskell might not do it directly like this internally, it is helpful to think about it this way :)

```
[x | Just x <- myList]
```

... becomes:

```
do
    Just x <- myList
    return x
```

... which is:

```
myList >>= \(Just x) -> return x
```

As to your question:

> What I don't understand is, how does Haskell know to call the "fail" function?

In do-notation, if a pattern binding fails (i.e. the `Just x`), then the fail method is called. For the above example, it would look something like this:

```
myList >>= \temp -> case temp of
    (Just x) -> return x
    _        -> fail "..."
```

So, every time you have a pattern-match in a monadic context that may fail, Haskell inserts a call to `fail`. Try it out with IO:

```
main = do
    (1,x) <- return (0,2)
    print x -- x would be 2, but the pattern match fails
```

Comment: Thank you! This response matches what I've been reading and explains the pattern-match behavior for types other than list. It hadn't occurred to me that the compiler might be using case statements like this to determine when to call fail. This totally makes sense.

Comment: "... which is: `myList >>= \(Just x) -> return x`" But it isn't that. If you write it like that, then it will throw a runtime error and won't call `fail`.

Answer (score 10):

The [rule for desugaring a list comprehension](http://haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions) requires an expression of the form `[ e | p <- l ]` (where `e` is an expression, `p` a pattern, and `l` a list expression) behave like

```
let ok p = [e]
    ok _ = []
in concatMap ok l
```

Previous versions of Haskell had [monad comprehensions](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/monads/monads.ps), which were removed from the language because they were hard to read and redundant with the `do`-notation. (List comprehensions are redundant, too, but they aren't so hard to read.) I *think* desugaring `[ e | p <- l ]` as a *monad* (or, to be precise, as a *monad with zero*) would yield something like

```
let ok p = return e
    ok _ = mzero
in l >>= ok
```

where `mzero` is from the `MonadPlus` class. This is very close to

```
do { p <- l; return e }
```

which [desugars](http://haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#do-expressions) to

```
let ok p = return e
    ok _ = fail "..."
in l >>= ok
```

When we take the List Monad, we have

```
return e = [e]
mzero = fail _ = []
(>>=) = flip concatMap
```

I.e., the 3 approaches (list comprehensions, monad comprehensions, `do` expressions) are equivalent for lists.

Comment: 'e' isn't necessarily of type List. Wouldn't it be "let ok p = [e]"? That would work. Regardless, if what you say is correct, then http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching must be wrong.

Comment: The Report says, "List comprehensions satisfy these identities"... not "you must translate them this way". They just have to work as though you have :)

Comment: That's true, Porges. But "X desugars to an expression which is observationally equivalent to Y" is a little much... ;-)

Comment: Monad comprehensions have returned to GHC as of version 7.2.1 - [(release notes)](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/release-7-2-1.html)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the list comprehension syntax has much to do with the fact that List (`[]`), or `Maybe` for that matter, happens to be an instance of the `Monad` type class.

List comprehensions are indeed *compiler magic* or *syntax sugar*, but that's possible because the compiler knows the structure of the `[]` data type.

Here's what the list comprehension is compiled to: (Well, I think, I didn't actually check it against the GHC)

```
xs = let f = \xs -> case xs of
                      Just x -> [x]
                      _      -> []
     in concatMap f myList
```

As you can see, the compiler doesn't have to call the `fail` function, it can simply inline a empty list, because it knows what a list *is*.

---

Interestingly, this fact that the list comprehensions syntax 'skips' pattern match failures is used in some libraries to do generic programming. See the example in the [Uniplate library](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Uniplate).

---

**Edit:** Oh, and to answer your question, you can't call your `select` function with the lambda you gave it. It will indeed fail on a pattern match failure if you call it with an `Nothing` value.

You could pass it the `f` function from the code above, but than `select` would have the type:

```
select :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

which is perfectly fine, you can use the `concatMap` function internally :-)

Also, that new `select` now has the type of the monadic bind operator for lists (with its arguments flipped):

```
(>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
xs >>= f = concatMap f xs -- 'or as you said: concat (map f xs)
```

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. What I read at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching about list comprehensions must be wrong then (it is a wiki, so I'm not surprised).

Comment: Sorry I unaccepted your answer, but I think Porges's is more accurate because it explains why List moands behave so much like list comprehensions.

Comment: I just wanted to say that there is nothing special about the way list comprehensions skip pattern match failures. That can be done in a ton of different ways. That uniplate example could just as easily have been written `variables x = universe x >>= \case Var x -> [x]; _ -> []` or with any other form of pattern matching.