# Only keep values that appear more than once within a list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

For example, if I have a list comprehension

```
comp :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
comp xs a b = [ y | x <- xs, y <- (func x a b) ]
```

where `func` is just the function

```
func :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
func x a b
   | (x == a || x == b  = [a,b]
   | otherwise          = filter (/=a) [a,b])
```

`comp` will typically give me duplicate values due to the way my `func` works.

i.e. I might get `comp = [1,2,2,3,3,4]` when passing some arbitrary `a` and `b`.

**My question is:** Is there any way I can only keep values in this list that appear more than once *within the list comprehension*? So that I instead get `comp = [2,3]` (since `2` and `3` appear more than once).

I understand there are many ways to do it outside of the list comprehension, but I want to know if it is possible to do it inside. Or could I even use a helper function to do this?

Comment: I’m almost certain there’s no way to do this with a list comprehension alone, since a list comprehension can only process one value at a time. But I won’t rule out some way I don‘t know about.

Comment: I've been trying to come up with an intelligent response, and I keep getting stuck on the definition of "within the list comprehension".  Does `[ y | y <- occursTwice (concatMap func xs) ]` count?

Comment: please edit the code so `comp`'s first argument is of type  `[Int]` and `func` has the parenthesis in the right spot.

Comment: Why is it important to do this with list comprehension?

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334410/getting-the-highest-integer-in-an-array-of-tuples ? I was about to post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with the help of `group`:

```
import Data.List

onlyDupes xs = [x | x:_:_ <- group xs]
```

It works like this:

```
λ> onlyDupes [1,2,2,3,3,4]
[2,3]
```

You could integrate that logic into your existing list comprehension like this:

```
comp xs a b = [ y | x <- xs, y:_:_ <- group (func x a b) ]
```

Note: if your values aren't always sorted like they are in your example, then you'll need to use `(group . sort)` instead of just `group`.

Comment: Interesting... If you are curious like me and want to know why exactly there is no **Non-exhaustive patterns** exception is thrown then you may check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/649274/4543207).